# Addition to DC/AC converter symbol

Tags: symbol

[image]

This image is of a DC/AC converter (inverter), but with the addition of a "C S" block to the left. What is the meaning of this additional block?

The wire at 9 o'clock is from an AC supply. This is from a UPS-type system

Comment: can you give us more of the circuit? Maybe (in fact, very often) the answer lies in the context.

Comment: I can't really give more of the circuit diagram, but it's a UPS-type layout. The DC entry (on the top) is the battery backup, and I think the side entry is the mains AC supply, but not sure.

Comment: Current sense output?